# How to update spring property place holder value after server startup

Tags: spring

I need to update or refresh property place holder value after server startup from DB.
As I have used custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer by extending in subclass as below.

**Custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class:**

```
public class PropertiesSourceImpl extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{    
 private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PropertiesSourceImpl.class);
 public PropertiesSourceImpl(){  }
 private int springSystemPropertiesMode =  SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE;

 private static Map<String, String> propertiesMap;
    @Override
    public void setSystemPropertiesMode(int systemPropertiesMode) {
    String updatedValue = loadFromDB();
        System.setProperty("newKey", updatedValue);
        super.setSystemPropertiesMode(systemPropertiesMode);
        springSystemPropertiesMode = systemPropertiesMode;
    }      

    public void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException {       
    String updatedValue = loadFromDB();
        props.setProperty("newKey", updatedValue); 

        super.loadProperties(props);

        propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = key.toString();

            String valueStr = resolvePlaceholder(keyStr, props);

            propertiesMap.put(keyStr, valueStr);                
        }           
      }

    public static String getProperty(String name) {
        return propertiesMap.get(name).toString();
    }       
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory){
        super.postProcessBeanFactory((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) factory);
    }
}
```

**Here is context.xml used spring 2.5.6**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<bean id="commonsUserManagementPropertyConfigurer" class="com.ebreez.utilities.PropertiesSourceImpl" scope="prototype" >
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>       
    <property name="properties">
    <props>
        <prop key="newKey">no-override</prop>
    </props>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean name="userManagementService"  class="com.ebreez.usermanagement.service.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl" 
scope="prototype">   
    <constructor-arg value="${newKey}" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**Here is the code where updating property value without restarting server:**

```
public class myBean{


public void updatePropertValue(){

    Properties props=new Properties();
    props.setProperty("newKey", "updatedValue");         

    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setProperties(props);
    //configurer.setSystemPropertiesMode(springSystemPropertiesMode);

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"context.xml"}, false);      
    configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    configurer.setSearchSystemEnvironment(false);
    //configurer.postProcessBeanFactory(applicationContext.getBeanFactory());
    applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);
    applicationContext.refresh();
}
}
```

But still value is **not** updating one in uerManagementServiceImpl.

Please let me know what wrong in my code to get updated value to be set for property place holder.

Comment: And how do you check if the property has been updated?

Comment: to check value need to add getNewKey() in constructor of UserManagementServiceImpl.java